# Accessing a local IIS server in a VM on a Mac from an iOS device for testing

Tags: macos, ios, windows, parallels-desktop, webserver

I have a Windows 10 install running in a Parallels VM on 2009 Mac Pro running OS X 10.11 and I want to access the IIS server in the VM for testing on iOS. I can reach website running in the VM from OS X without issue, but when I try and access it through an iOS device through an ad-hoc network or through the same wifi network it doesn't respond, but I am able to access websites hosted in OS X on the iOS device.

I don't want to use a third party solution, I just want local access that I can control. Has anyone been able to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

Change your network setting in parallels to be bridge mode and you should be set.

- http://kb.parallels.com/en/4948

The IIS and Windows will get their own IP address so you can connect as if the PC was a physical one connected directly to the network. The Mac won't see the traffic to the server process.